# Access Current Open SQL Connection

Tags: sql, winforms, database-connection

My app is a WinForms database app.  The connection to the db happens behind the scenes during startup using a connection string in settings.  Works fine.  The application synchronizes the local db to an Azure db using Sync Framework 2.1.  This requires first setting up both ends of the connection.  The Azure end is easy.  I simply set up a new connection.  I'm having trouble with the local end.  I can't set up a new connection because there already is one and it's open.  I need to use this open connection but don't know how to access it.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean the connection happens behind the scenes? What proof do you have of this?

Comment: This is standard WinForms operation.  The connection is created and opened in designer code.

Comment: No magic, search you code, find where is the "behind scenes"